# Edit .ini file in Delphi to change full paths

Tags: delphi, path, edit, filepath, ini

Hi guys im a newbie and need some help in Delphi

I need help to delphi read a example.ini file and change in path= to current path
and savepath= to currentpath\saves

Thanks

Comment: You should first read dcomentation on [TIniFile](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.IniFiles.TIniFile). There you can read how Delphi is handling Ini Files and even find an example code which should help you start.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you asked for (coded in Delphi 10.3 CE):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.IniFiles;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  path: string;
  savepath: string;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ini: TIniFile;
begin
  // Extract current directory
  path := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));

  Ini := TIniFile.Create(path + 'example.ini');
  try
    path:= Ini.ReadString('General', 'OpenPath', path);
    savepath:= Ini.ReadString('General', 'SavePath', path + 'saves/');
  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
var Ini: TIniFile;
begin
  Ini := TIniFile.Create(path + 'example.ini');
  try
    Ini.WriteString('General', 'OpenPath', path);
    Ini.WriteString('General', 'SavePath', savepath);
  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;
  CanClose:= true;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks bro, i have Embarcadero Delphi XE, but all my projects from Delphi 7 works on Delphi XE, i will try tonight and let u know if works :) Thanks you so very much

Comment: Thanks but get multiple errors on Embarcadero Delphi XE

Comment: @johndoe Normally the only thing you have to update is the `uses` part which differ slightly in more recent Delphi versions. I updated my code to the latest Delphi version I own (Delphi 10.3 Community Edition)

Comment: I did bro, thanks a lot for your help, i could write totally the .ini on delphi from 0, the issue of this is the app everytime change parameters on .ini and open the project will reset all the configurations on .ini then i just needed read the path and savepath to write just there. I used before Borland Delphi 7 but i stop to used bcuz all my project (simply apps) has been flagged by lot of free-antivirs like troyans even when i have a clean code that its a false alarm, so i have to move from Delphi 7 to Embarcadero Delphi XE, and all my project compiled are clean of false alarms.  THANKS!!!